# Implementation of Quantum PAC learning classifier

Tags: quantum-enhanced-machine-learning

I am working on a project related to Boosting of Quantum Classifiers of PAC format. And I am a little confused about how do we go about implementing a PAC classifier. The basic idea is that we have to use multiple copies(say Q) of the state
$$
\sum_{x \in \{ 0,1 \}^n } \sqrt{D(x_i)} |x_i, y_i = c(x_i)>
$$

where in order to train our classifier. On further exploring the [paper](https://homepages.cwi.nl/%7Erdewolf/publ/qc/sigact_arxiv.pdf) pointed out that we need to measure out the above state and then use the samples in order to train the classifier.

So assuming that I have access to such a state, would measuring out the state and then using Q states out of all the obtained states in order to train a classifier such as QNN or QSVM, accomplish the said task.

Furthermore lets say I have the $ D(x_i)$ and $(x_i, y_i)$ is there even any need to create the said state, or just directly using these to train our model enough ??